# repaint the signal sometimes Need help to convert Pinescript to none repaint

Tags: pine-script

```
`//@version=2
strategy("")

threshold = input(title="Price Difference Threshold", type=float, defval=0, step=0.001)

getDiff() =>
yesterday=security(tickerid, 'D', close[1])
today=security(tickerid, 'D', close)
delta=today-yesterday
percentage=delta/yesterday

closeDiff = getDiff()

buying = closeDiff > threshold ? true : closeDiff < -threshold ? false : buying[1]

hline(0, title="zero line")

bgcolor(buying ? #3399FF : #FFFFFF , transp=1)
plot(closeDiff, color=silver, style=area, transp=75)
plot(closeDiff, color=aqua, title="prediction")

longCondition = buying
if (longCondition)
strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)

shortCondition = buying != true
if (shortCondition)
strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)`
```

I have pasted Pinescript above it repaint the signal sometimes, so I am asking some help to convert this signal into none repaint. I would really appreciate any help. Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait until the HTF bar is closed if you want to [avoid repainting when using secuirty()](https://www.tradingview.com/script/cyPWY96u-How-to-avoid-repainting-when-using-security-PineCoders-FAQ/).

You can use the below function:

```
f_secureSecurity(_symbol, _res, _src) => security(_symbol, _res, _src[1], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
```

Comment: I don't have knowledge of coding. Can you tell where the function you have asked to use has to be added in the script?
Or can you send a completely new one by adding this function to the script?
I will be helped by you. Thank you